# Python debugging with "assert" when using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, multiprocessing, assert

I have a specific version of [this question on debugging multiprocessing in Python](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126940/debug-multiprocessing-in-python). I use `assert` statements extensively throughout my code to catch bugs. When a false assert fires, the program stops, and the file name and line number of the offending `assert` is printed to stderr.

However when I used `multiprocessing.Pool`, all I get back is that there was an `AssertionError` but no information about where the offending `assert` is.

For example, the following minimal code uses multiprocessing `map` for `cores >= 2' and regular`map`function for`cores == 1`:

```
import multiprocessing
import logging

mpl = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
mpl.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def test(foo):
    print foo
    assert False

cores = 2

if cores > 1:
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)
    pool.map(test, range(cores))
else:
    map(test, range(cores))
```

For `cores == 1` I get the following error:

```
File "test_multiprocessing.py", line 16, in test
    assert False
```

For `cores == 2` I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
```

If you notice, I tried the [logging answer suggest here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/170865/25589) but that doesn't provide the assert information either.

Is there a way using `multiprocessing` module or any other threading module to get the location of an offending `assert` statement?

Comment: Huh, you'd think that the father of theoretical computer science would have more rep.